# Django creating super user error: AttributeError: 'ProfileManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I am trying to create a superuser, however, after I added my own ProfileManager I get the error:

`AttributeError: 'ProfileManager' object has no attribute 'create_superuser'`

But my issue is should BaseUserManager already have this method? I cannot find a why to inherit the `create_superuser` method.

My manager is:

```
class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
      pass
```

And my model is:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
      
      objects = ProfileManager()
```

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`BaseUserManager`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e02738bf55f66939be63f75d4fdcdc2ebc36e435/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L17) class does not have `create_superuser` nor `create_user`, these methods are implemented in [`UserManager`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L129)

Which is also documented in customizing authentication [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model)

> If your user model defines username, email, is_staff, is_active,
> is_superuser, last_login, and date_joined fields the same as Django’s
> default user, you can install Django’s UserManager; however, if your
> user model defines different fields, you’ll need to define a custom
> manager that extends BaseUserManager providing two additional methods:

- create_user
- create_superuser

So you don't need to set objects attribute nor override anything as [`AbstractUser`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/e02738bf55f66939be63f75d4fdcdc2ebc36e435/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L358) sets objects attribute to

```
 objects = UserManager()
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `BaseUserManager` doesn't have that method, but [**`UserManager`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager) does

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager


class ProfileManager(UserManager):
    pass
```